# Matlab custom spherical bessel function NaN at 0

Tags: matlab, math, bessel-functions

I have a problem involved spherical Bessel functions of order 0. I wrote my own spherical Bessel function:

```
function js = sphbesselj(nu,x)
js = sqrt(pi ./(2* x)) .* besselj(nu + 0.5, x);
end
```

which seems to agree with Mathematicas inbuilt one for all my test cases. The problem is at `nu` or `x =0`. Mathematica correctly returns 1, but my MATLAB scrip returns NaN. How could I correct my code, so that if I feed in an array of say `x = 0:1:5` I get the 1 for my first value, instead of

```
>> sphbesselj(0,x)
ans =
   NaN    0.8415    0.4546    0.0470   -0.1892   -0.1918
```

Is my custom function the best way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: Dividing by zero is always going to give you problems. Why not just catch the x=0 case and modify accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, floating point values of `x` close to `0` also return `Nan`. You actually have three cases to possibly worry about. x = ±∞ results in `NaN` as well. Here's a vectorized function that handles those:

```
function js = sphbesselj(nu,x)
    if isscalar(nu) && isscalar(x)
        js = 0;
    elseif isscalar(nu)
        js = zeros(size(x));
        nu = js+nu;
    else
        js = zeros(size(nu));
        x = js+x;
    end
    x0 = (abs(x) < realmin);
    x0nult0 = (x0 & nu < 0);
    x0nueq0 = (x0 & nu == 0);
    js(x0nult0) = Inf;          % Re(Nu) < 0, X == 0
    js(x0nueq0) = 1;            % Re(Nu) == 0, X == 0
    i = ~x0nult0 & ~x0nueq0 & ~(x0 & nu > 0) & (abs(x) < realmax);
    js(i) = sign(x(i)).*sqrt(pi./(2*x(i))).*besselj(nu(i)+0.5,x(i));
end
```

A useful resource when developing such functions is http://functions.wolfram.com. The page on the [spherical Bessel function of the first kind](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/SphericalBesselJ/) has many useful relationships.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this function is very clever and I learnt some new tricks from it. I have run into a new problem now though. The function returns 1 when x is any negative number. I can't quite work out how to edit it to re allow negative values again. Thanks!

Comment: @SteveHatcher: You're correct. I've updated the code. That issue was fixed by `x0 = (abs(x) < realm in);`. I also made two other small changes to match Mathematica's `SphericalBesselJ`. In particular, the sign of the output seems to depend on the sign of `x`. This doesn't seem to be indicated by the definition of the function, but it makes sense as this is a spherical function.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much - that works perfectly! Yes Mathematica does seem to presume more about situations to make things simpler. I am still surprised MATLAB does not have spherical bessel built in functions.